# Indicator loop doesn't work on Expert Advisor

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I am not sure what is wrong on the indicator indices, but when I try to print the data in my custom indicator the result is zero.

In this indicator I am using multiple EMAs for open, close, high, prices
The output should be a band which I can use when I add the indicator into a chart, it doesn't work properly on a Expert Advisor in Metatrader 5.

I can for loop the buffers using `rates_total` but I think it is wrong since a test in the expert advisor runs very slowly.

```
//--- input parameters
input int      period=100;
input int      smoothing=100;
input int      osc_period=7;
input double   mul1=1.0;
input double   mul2=1.0;
//--- indicator buffers
double         ha_highBuffer[];
double         ha_lowBuffer[];
double         oBuffer[];
double         cBuffer[];
double         hBuffer[];
double         lBuffer[];
int oHandle, cHandle, hHandle, lHandle;
int OnInit()
  {
   SetIndexBuffer(0,ha_highBuffer,INDICATOR_DATA);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,ha_lowBuffer,INDICATOR_DATA);
    //let o = EMA(open, period)
    //let c = EMA(close, period)
    //let h = EMA(high, period)
    //let l = EMA(low, period)
    oHandle = iMA(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,period,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_OPEN);
    cHandle = iMA(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,period,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE);
    hHandle = iMA(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,period,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_HIGH);
    lHandle = iMA(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,period,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_LOW);
   
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[]){
   int start=prev_calculated;
   int to_copy=(rates_total!=prev_calculated)?rates_total-prev_calculated:1;  
   Print("Start:",start,"End:",start+to_copy,"RatesTotal:",rates_total);  

   CopyBuffer(oHandle,0,0,to_copy,oBuffer);
   CopyBuffer(cHandle,0,0,to_copy,cBuffer);
   CopyBuffer(hHandle,0,0,to_copy,hBuffer);
   CopyBuffer(lHandle,0,0,to_copy,lBuffer);
   /*CopyBuffer(oHandle,0,0,rates_total,oBuffer);
   CopyBuffer(cHandle,0,0,rates_total,cBuffer);
   CopyBuffer(hHandle,0,0,rates_total,hBuffer);
   CopyBuffer(lHandle,0,0,rates_total,lBuffer);*/
   //Print("SIZE",ArraySize(oBuffer));
   
   
   //haclose = avg(o, h, l, c)
   //haopen = (o+c)/2
   //hahigh = max(h, max(haopen, haclose)
   //halow = min(l, min(haopen, haclose)
   //hahigh = EMA(hahigh, smoothing)
   //halow = EMA(halow, smoothing)

   //for(int i=0; i<rates_total; i++) //this works fine but it is very slow
   
   for(int i=0, j=prev_calculated; i<to_copy; i++, j++){ //Here!! I am not sure about the parameters
      double haclose = (oBuffer[i]+cBuffer[i]+hBuffer[i]+lBuffer[i])/4;
      double haopen = (oBuffer[i]+cBuffer[i])/2;
      ha_highBuffer[j] = MathMax(hBuffer[i],MathMax(haopen,haclose));
      ha_lowBuffer[j] = MathMin(lBuffer[i],MathMin(haopen,haclose));
      int n = smoothing;
      if(j!=0){
         ha_highBuffer[j] = 2.0 / (n+1) * (ha_highBuffer[j] - ha_highBuffer[j-1]) + ha_highBuffer[j-1];
         ha_lowBuffer[j] = 2.0 / (n+1) * (ha_lowBuffer[j] - ha_lowBuffer[j-1]) + ha_lowBuffer[j-1];
      }
   }
```

Output using my attempt at optimizing the indicator

```
2023.10.09 22:27:36.974 Core 01 2023.01.01 00:00:00   Start:0 End:74536 RatesTotal:74536
2023.10.09 22:27:36.974 Core 01 2023.01.02 00:05:00   Start:74536 End:74538 RatesTotal:74538
2023.10.09 21:52:51.728 Core 01 2023.10.06 23:25:00   ema:1.0587247213275528 indicator:0.0 0.0
2023.10.09 21:52:51.728 Core 01 2023.10.06 23:30:00   ema:1.0586697770620423 indicator:0.0 0.0
2023.10.09 21:52:51.728 Core 01 2023.10.06 23:35:00   ema:1.0586498216496338 indicator:0.0 0.0
2023.10.09 21:52:51.728 Core 01 2023.10.06 23:40:00   ema:1.0586278573197072 indicator:0.0 0.0
2023.10.09 21:52:51.728 Core 01 2023.10.06 23:45:00   ema:1.0586242858557657 indicator:0.0 0.0
2023.10.09 21:52:51.728 Core 01 2023.10.06 23:50:00   ema:1.0585614286846128 indicator:0.0 0.0
2023.10.09 21:52:51.728 Core 01 2023.10.06 23:55:00   ema:1.0585211429476904 indicator:0.0 0.0
```